# Is it possible to force Github Desktop to show repo cloned from command line?

Tags: git, github, windows-7-x64, github-for-windows

On windows 7 64-bit when I clone a Github repo cmd.exe by running something like this;

`cd Documents\github
git clone git://github.com/username/repo.git`

Then I open Github desktop and the cloned repo isn't there. I know that I can clone repos through Github desktop and that's great but what I want to know is; can I some how force Github desktop to recognize a repo cloned through the command line?

Comment: I don't see how this could be achieved without scanning your filesystem periodically and then adding the repos found to github desktop. So in a nutshell I don't think this can be done easily.

Comment: @RaduDita what about some kind of batch file or python script that would run the regular clone command on a repo and then append that cloned directory to the Github desktop internal data files? Could something like that work?

Comment: Yeah, that could work, but I was under the impression that you want any git clone to be added to gitdesktop, in that case you'll still have repos that aren't added

Comment: @RaduDita yes it for github desktop would be nice to be able to track changes to any and all cloned repos on a disk. A solution like that would call for a mthod like you suggested earlier. However what I would like is some kind of method that automatically links repos to github desktop when I use the command `git clone`. Honestly I'm surprised someone hasn't done this already. Also I emailed github support about this and they said running this should work `github path\to\repository` I tried with no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

A partial solution from Steve Ward at Github support;
Open **Git Shell**, which should automatically start in your Github directory then run the following commands;

`git clone git://github.com/username/repo-name.git
github repo-name`

Github desktop will launch and you should see `repo-name` load.

I still would like to see a single step automated solution that could be run from the cmd.exe as well git shell but that sounds like it doesn't exist. But anyone figures it out post it here and I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a '+' in the upper left corner which allows adding a repository that was not cloned through the application.

[More](https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/contributing/adding-a-repository-from-your-local-computer-to-github-desktop/)

Comment: I understand that. what I want is a command line tool that achieves the same end. Does that make sense?

Comment: Um, well Github Desktop uses an internal data file for mapping repos to their location. You can edit this data file in order to add a new repo. I'm not aware of an existing tool that does this and this wouldn't be a supported operation by the application, so it may break with future updates. Is your goal to create a hook that adds to the application on clone?

Comment: I'd like to have the repos that I clone through the command line to automatically show up in github desktop.